# How to prevent closing InputStream by AutoCloseInputStream

Tags: java, android, inputstream

What I want to do: open InputStream for big file, read it by 10MB chunks, upload a chunk, read next chunk.

```
val chunkCount = Math.ceil(totalSize.toDouble() / chunkSize.toDouble()).toInt()
for (chunkNumber in (0..chunkCount-1)) {
    var chunk = ByteArray(chunkSize)
    val currentChunkSize = inputStream.read(chunk)
    if (chunk.size != currentChunkSize) { //last chunk
        chunk = chunk.copyOf(currentChunkSize)
    }
    // uploading of chunk
}
```

I wrote good code for this task, but the problem is the ContentResolver returns ParcelFileDescriptor.AutoCloseInputStream as InputStream. This implementation breaks a contract of InputStream, because it closes itself after first .read(), so when I am trying to read next chunk, I am getting IOException - "The stream was closed".

I don't want get the whole array at first .read(), because file can be large, and it will worsen perfomance or can call OutOfMemory error.

How to prevent closing InputStream by AutoCloseInputStream, or make ContentResolver return normal FileInputStream?

**UPDATED**

Problem is not in AutoCloseInputStream, but in Android system, which closes the stream if application memory is low.

Comment: This is not Java. It might be Scala, or JavaScript. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @EJP code is not Java, it is Kotlin. But it is Java problem. InputStream and AutoCloseInputStream are java classes

Comment: And it turned out that it wasn't.  I expect a question tagged with Java and nothing else not to contain code that isn't Java. Kindly adjust your tags. Or remove your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is not in AutoCloseInputStream, but in Android system. It closes the stream when memory is low.

I resolved it just with reopening stream and calling InputStream.skip(offset: long)

Comment: how to reopen it ?

Answer (score 1):

Please dont downvote its more of a comment for additional info but kinda long with code in it. 
I thought AutoCloseInputStream only closed inputStream when it reached end of file

To do chunks would you need to call read like this?  where the len is the chunk size and off is where your last chunk upload offset needs to be

```
int read (byte[] b, int off, int len)
```

The read(b, off, len) method for class InputStream simply calls the method read() repeatedly. If the first such call results in an IOException, that exception is returned from the call to the read(b, off, len) method. If any subsequent call to read() results in a IOException, the exception is caught and treated as if it were end of file; the bytes read up to that point are stored into b and the number of bytes read before the exception occurred is returned.

Comment: I am already using an alias of this function: public int read(byte b[]) throws IOException {
        return read(b, 0, b.length);
    } //code is taken from java.io.InputStream source

Comment: ok that makes sense. have you tried to make another call to read immediately after and see if it returns -1 from looking at api documentation my gut tells me it might be an end of file  issue

Comment: So you are right, the problem is not in AutoCloseInputStream, but in Android system. It closes the stream when memory is low. Setting android:largeHeap to true doesn't help :(